# Site Logos Not Readable on OData

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

If you look at some of the logos on http://odata.stackexchange.com/, specifically Photography and AskUbuntu, you'll see the problem.

These logos were meant for dark backgrounds (the site name is white), however OData has a white background, making them invisible.

Comment: Also, Game Development logo extends past the other columns

Comment: ... and Webmaster's look very ugly

Answer (score 2):

Fixed at http://data.stackexchange.com added a background color that is settable for each site.