# Some logos in data explorer clash with page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, data-explorer

Some of the logos on the main page of the data explorer are too narrow or have the same colour text as the background.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Site Logos Not Readable on OData](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70632/site-logos-not-readable-on-odata)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed it so we can specify the bg color for any site ... this is fixed at http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: Will this change be applied to other pages also? For example, the same logo problem affects the Browse Queries pages. For example: http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/queries